# Circular dependency detected with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

Face issue while pick data from another sheet using 
Vlookup Formula

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,July!L2:L3,3,FALSE)
```

**Screenshots :**
[Main Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0DEP.jpg)
[July Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65B52.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling the formula to look up a value in column 3 (`VLOOKUP(,,*3*,)`) of a 1 column range (`VLOOKUP(,*July!L2:L3*,,)`). You need to change the range you are looking up the value in to a larger range. You also might want to make the range an absolute range as opposed to relative. For example try:

```
=VLOOKUP(B$1,July!$K$2:$L$4,2,FALSE)
```

Edit: B2 changed to B$1 as per @Scott's comment

Comment: It is also referring to itself. Change B2 to B$1